# How do I make a call from a gRPC server to another gRPC server in C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, grpc, grpc-c#

I'm using C# in Visual Studio 2022 to create two gRPC servers as Windows services.  Each of these services were created from choosing the desired template in VS.  Each has their own client also created from VS templates... meaning there is a lot of generated code in both the client and server that I didn't write.

From one Windows service I would like to call the other Windows service preferably the same way the client calls the service.

```
string address = "https://localhost:6224"; 
using GrpcChannel channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(address);

var client = new CADEservice.CADEserviceClient(channel);
CADErequest cr = new CADErequest();
cr.Code = "sql";
cr.Data = "select org_int,org_name from organization";
var reply = client.SendMessage(cr);
```

Protobuf

```
message CADErequest {
    string Code = 1;
    string Data = 2;
```

Unfortunately, this is my first venture into gRPC and I can't find any examples or discussions on how to do this.

So, I guess I have two questions: (1) Is it possible to do what I'm asking and (2) Is there  an example I can follow anywhere?

Comment: Example is the same as you would do a "normal" client code for the gRPC service ... forget that this is also a gRPC server and treat your project as normal client project

Comment: But I created the gRPC Client as a stand-alone client from a template that generated a lot of "client" code.  I can't do the same thing when the project (server) already exists.

Comment: but you have 2 servers ... you may use create projects [like this](https://share.sketchpad.app/23/495-eba5-c5fe16.png) ... Where Client 2 library has all client code generated and Client 2 just use this library and server 1 also use this library to connect to Server 2 ...

Comment: Any examples of creating such a "client library"?  I've got no clue how to do that.  There's nothing I've seen that addresses something like that.

Comment: This is probably way too late, but the client library would most likely simply be a C# project containing a C# gRPC client as usual, nothing crazy. You can also have gRPC client and server in the same C# project, nothing stops you from doing that to my knowledge.